# How can I compile a .cs file into a .exe on a Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

I'm reading "Fundamentals of Computer Programming with C#". I am using a Mac, but much of this book (so far) is geared toward Windows users. The instructions for compiling a cs into a .exe file involve using the csc.exe compiler. It says to cd into the folder where the cs file is and type:

```
 csc fileName.cs
```

It predicts that this will cause an error, which it does:

```
 bash: csc: command not found
```

It then says to get around this error, I should provide the full path of the compiler in the terminal command, but this does not work and I receive the same error. I've googled the problem, but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Update: To whomever suggested mono, that was it. Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/

Comment: simple C# programs can also be compiled and run online if you google for example "C# online"

Comment: @Lext Li But I use Visual Studio Code